# Excel: how to merge duplicate rows of a column , leaving the rest of column data as it is

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

My Excel will be populated using query now the below is the data set which is coming!

```
COL A                                         COL B     COL C  COL D
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan              0%    0 
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan    1         20%   0 
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan    2,3       50%   0 
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan    4,5       100%  0 
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan    6         150%  0 
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan    Unrated   50%   0 
Claims on Banks                                           0%    245,608 
Claims on Banks                                           10%   0 
Claims on Banks                                  1        20%   0 
Claims on Banks                                2,3        50%   0 
Claims on Banks                                4,5        100%  0 
Claims on Banks                                6          150%  0 
Claims on Banks                                Unrated    50%   0
```

and what i want is

```
COL A                                         COL B     COL C  COL D
Claims on Public Sector Entities in Pakistan              0%    0 
                                                1         20%   0 
                                                2,3       50%   0 
                                                4,5       100%  0 
                                                6         150%  0 
                                                Unrated   50%   0 
Claims on Banks                                           0%    245,608 
                                                          10%   0 
                                                 1        20%   0 
                                               2,3        50%   0 
                                               4,5        100%  0 
                                               6          150%  0 
                                               Unrated    50%   0
```

i want my column A to get merge but i want my other columns data as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula to output value from column A only if it is different from previous row is:

```
=IF(A2 = A1, "", A2)
```

but it is not possible to update cells in-place with plain formulas, you can:

- copy the computed cells and paste special as values back into column A
- add a new column between A and B, insert the formula and then hide the original column A,
- use the formula on another sheet, together with formula `=B2` for the other columns
- use a VBA macro

Comment: Thank you Aprillion for your help it works, i improvised it a bit so it display correct data =IF(A1=A0," ",A1). I cant vote up your answer as i don't have enough reputation as i am newbie